# iOS standalone webapp iframe cookies

Tags: iframe, cookies, ios-web-app

I am using iOS webapp which has iFrames in it. Those iFrames point to other cross-domain applications. When I login to those apps in iFrames the login doesn't happen. This is because iFrame in iOS standalone web app doesn't store the response cookies sent by the apps in iFrames thereby unable to save session data.
This problem is only in iOS standalone web app. It works fine in Safari.
I need to be able to use the iFrames in the iOS standalone web app and store cookie information coming from the responses of the iFrame apps in thier respective iFrames.
If anyone has possible solutions please help.

Comment: Does anyone know how to save cookies in iFrames inside a standalone iOS web app?